# how to hide the dropdown icon of combobox

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have an application using `ComboBox` with `ComboBox.DropDownStyle = DropDown`, I want to hide the dropdown button of it, and `dropdownitems` will be displayed programmatically, when required.

How could I accomplish that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than "Hide" the arrow, could you not just set the control to Enable = False?

Comment: I want user to use combobox as textbox and dropdown will be displayed programmatically

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renee147's was a good suggestion in that you seldom want to mix metaphors with UI elements.

But, if you REALLY needed to hide the dropdown arrow, I'd just stick a picture box on the form and size/move it to fit just over the arrow portion of the combo. Not technically sophisticated, but it'd work.

Comment: This was really quick & simple workaround, although not sophisticated as you said but rocks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ComboBox.DropDownStyle = Simple

Comment: `and dropdownitems will be displayed`  Your solution ignores that.

Comment: Use DropDownHeight = 1 for a Dropdown box without displaying dropdownitems. This may make the bottom line of the combobox 1 pixel higher. In my app this is no problem. Maybe this simple solution will suffice for others too.